# Finding ways to achieve a target sum using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, combinatorics

I need your review and suggestions how to make this code better. I'm just learning recursion and sure that this solution is not ideal.

**Question:**

Write a function that given an input array of integers with a varying length input integers array, and the desired target_sum, returns the number of combinations, of any length, that add up to that target_sum.

**EXAMPLE 1:**

total_combinations = calculate_combinations([5, 5, 15, 10], target_sum=15)

**ANSWER 1:**

Should return 3, as there are 3 combinations of numbers from the input array that add up to 15, namely:

15 5+10 5+10 10

solution:

```
private static int mainfunction(int[] input, int target)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = mainfunction_slave(input, i, target, 1);
        result = result + temp;
    }
    return result;
}
private static int mainfunction_slave(int[] input, int index, int target, int check)
{
    if ((index  + check) > (input.Length - 1))
        return 0;
    if ((input[index] + input[index + check]) == target || (input[index] == target))
        return mainfunction_slave(input, index, target, check + 1) + 1;
    return mainfunction_slave(input, index, target, check + 1);
}
```

- The task needs to be done via recursion, but if you have any other better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't `mainfunction(new[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 3)` return 1?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling you are asking us to do your homework for you 

Comment: "of any length" indicate you have to get all possible combinations of number but you are only checking 1 and 2 value combinations. What if adding 3 or more values together equals the target_sum? Also do you have to consider that one or more values can be 0? That opens up a whole host of combinations.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of quick notes:

- Methods in C# should be named `PascalCase`.
- `mainfunction` isn't a great name. It should be named by what it does
- `mainfunction_slave` is also a bad name, you shouldn't use underscores in method names in C#

---

You need to plan your recursion:

1. What's the base case?
2. What can you make smaller/approach the base case as you go?

The base case is fairly trivial:

If the array has 1 element, return whether that element matches the target.

```
static int CalculateCombinations(int[] numbers, int target)
{
    // trivial solution:
    if (numbers.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // base case:
    if (numbers.Length == 1)
    {
        return numbers[0] == target ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Cool, we could now (or even before this) write a test or two:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaclculateCombinationsWithSingleElement()
{
    var numbers = new[] { 1 };
    var target = 1;

    var result = YourClass.CalculateCombinations(numbers, target);

     Assert.AreEqual(1, result);
}
```

(I don't use MSTest myself so not sure if the above is 100% correct).

Now you need to think about how to split the problem up. Recursion on a list is almost always making the list smaller at each step.

The number of combinations is:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    // are we at a solution ?
    if (numbers[i] == target)
    {
        count++;
    }

    // find solutions that sum to the current target - the current number
    // on remainder of the array
    var subArray = numbers.Skip(i + 1).ToArray();
    count += CalculateCombinations(subArray, target - numbers[i]);
 }
 return count;
```

If you only consider positive integers, it looks like `target` is getting smaller too but actually only the `numbers` array is getting 'smaller' as negative numbers or 0s don't make target closer to 0.

That makes the whole solution something like:

```
static int CalculateCombinations(int[] numbers, int target)
{
    if (numbers.Length == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (numbers.Length == 1)
    {
        return numbers[0] == target ? 1 : 0;
    }

    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == target)
        {
            count++;
        }
        var subArray = numbers.Skip(i + 1).ToArray();
        count += CalculateCombinations(subArray, target - numbers[i]);
    }
    return count;
}
```

---

**Update**:

On reflection, the base case can simply be an empty array. We don't need to worry about the length = 1 case because it would have been counted in the for loop anyway.

That means the code can be simplified to:

```
static int CalculateCombinations(int[] numbers, int target)
{
        if (numbers.Length == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] == target)
            {
                count++;
            }
            var subArray = numbers.Skip(i + 1).ToArray();
            count += CalculateCombinations(subArray, target - numbers[i]);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I'd recommend [The Little Schemer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/548914.The_Little_Schemer) as a great introduction to recursion. One of the commandments is:

> Simplify only after the function is correct.

So I don't feel too bad about overcomplicating it the first time :)